# Why is nothing being added to the ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, tostring

So here's what I am doing. I create a book, I add the book to an inventory class that extends an inventory of overall products (contains the arraylist for the program) with this:

```
    myBookInventory.addProduct(myBook);
```

Which comes from:

```
    super.addProduct(pBook); // From BookInventory class that extends ProductInventory class
```

Which contains the following code:

```
     public void addProduct(Product pProduct)
{

    // Add the new product to the product inventory array list
    myProductInventory.add(pProduct);


}
```

ProductInventory has an arraylist called myProductInventory. What I want to do is display the information of that product. Here's what I use:

```
    for (Product product: productList.myProductInventory) {
                System.out.println(product);
            }
```

Problem occurs here in this System.out. It does not display anything, and I have no idea why. I'm open to any solution. If there's anything missing that you'd like for me to show you, just let me know.

Comment: It would be beneficial to you and to us to provide a more concise example: http://sscce.org/

Comment: What is addBookInventory() doing? I don't think you've shown that.

Comment: I would also recommend to take a look at Builder pattern to avoid that many constructors in Book class.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a debugger.

Comment: Most likely you are not adding to the list you eventually use. I would step through the code in your debugger and ensure there is only one list and you use that list all the way through.

Comment: @PeterLawrey the only arraylist in the entire program is myProductInventory

Comment: @user3108443 That's what you've intended but that doesn't mean it's true. In fact, looking at the edits before you removed the source, it's clear there are at least two lists because Menu (which has a ProductInventory) extends InventoryProgram (which has a BookInventory).

Comment: @Radiodef the BookInventory class does not instantiate an arraylist, nor does the InventoryProgram class. But what you're saying is that because BookInventory extends ProductInventory, there are two lists?

Comment: @user3108443 So you could make the reference final and make sure it never changes.

Comment: Yes. If BookInventory extends ProductInventory then BookInventory inherits ProductInventory's ArrayList. So if you create a BookInventory and a ProductInventory there are two ArrayLists because both have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like new books are added to `InventoryProgram`'s `myBookInventory`, but you are displaying books from `Menu`'s `productList`, which is still empty.

Comment: But myBookInventory is an object of BookInventory which extends ProductInventory, using the arraylist myProductInventory. So my question is, if books are not being added to my arraylist, then what are my objects doing?

Comment: When `Menu` is created it has two inventories: `productList` (created in `Menu`) and `myBookInventory` (created via inheritance). You are adding books to one and displaying the other.

Answer (score 0):

From user3108443L:

" I did the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myBookInventory.getSize(); i++) {
            System.out.println(myBookInventory.getProduct(i));
        }
```

This printed out exactly what I wanted. "